# Launching EC2 instance into vpc and with a public IP

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-vpc

```
InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification vpc = new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
{
SubnetId = "subnet-sadfsadf",
    AssociatePublicIpAddress = true,
    DeleteOnTermination = false

};
List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification> temp= new List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification>();
            temp.Add(vpc);

//Create and initialize a RunInstanceRequest
RunInstancesRequest newInstanceRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
{
   ImageId = appdbAMI,
   InstanceType = appdbType,
   MinCount = 1,
   MaxCount = appdbQuantity,
   KeyName = ec2Key,
   NetworkInsterfaces = temp,
   BlockDeviceMappings = resp.Images[0].BlockDeviceMappings
   //DisableApiTermination = true
};
```

This does not launch an instance into the vpc with a public ip address. What is wrong with it? I want to launch an instance into a vpc that also assigns it a public ip address.

Comment: What does it do ?  Can you provide some logs ?

Comment: Thanks! I always forget to check my logs! I'll post what I have now just for future reference.

Comment: Can you just add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

CORRECT FORMAT: 
I forgot to add the device index in the instance network interface specification.
I create the string list for the security groups. 
I then create the createnetworkinterfacerequest object and add the subnet id and security groups. 
Then create the createnetworkinterfaceresponse object and create the interface. 
Next I create the instancenetworkinterfacespecification item and add it to the list. 
Last I run the runinstancerequest and bam, it worked.

```
List<string> secgrps = new List<string>(new string[] { "sg-2143", "sg-1234" });
CreateNetworkInterfaceRequest cnireq = new CreateNetworkInterfaceRequest()
{ 
SubnetId = "subnet-1234", 
Groups = secgrps 
};
CreateNetworkInterfaceResponse cniresp = ec2Client.CreateNetworkInterface(cnireq);
InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification inis = new InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification()
{ 
SubnetId = cniresp.NetworkInterface.SubnetId, 
Groups = secgrps, 
AssociatePublicIpAddress = true, 
DeviceIndex=0 
};
List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification> inisList = new List<InstanceNetworkInterfaceSpecification>();
inisList.Add(inis);

//Create and initialize a RunInstanceRequest
RunInstancesRequest newInstanceRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
{
    ImageId = appdbAMI,
    InstanceType = appdbType,
    MinCount = 1,
    MaxCount = appdbQuantity,
    KeyName = ec2Key,
    //SecurityGroups = appdbSecurity,
    NetworkInterfaces = inisList,
    BlockDeviceMappings = resp.Images[0].BlockDeviceMappings
    //DisableApiTermination = true
};
```

Comment: Why do you create the "cnireq" ? SubnetId = cniresp.NetworkInterface.SubnetId should be the specified final subnet ID that you used for the cni, here : "subnet-1234"